# Datatable: date / time sorting plug-in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable, datatables

I want to order 1 date column of a datatable.
this is my piece of code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>

<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'EEEE, MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a' );

    $('#table').dataTable( {  
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 25,
    }); 
} );
</script>
```

but I got this error:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function TypeError: $.fn.dataTable.moment is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure moments.js is reference **before** the plug-in

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.8.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>

<script th:inline="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.fn.dataTable.moment( 'EEEE, MMMM d,yyyy h:mm,a' );

    $('#table').dataTable( {  
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "pageLength": 25,
    }); 
} );
</script>
```